# How to add the cart summary to contact us page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, layout

I have made a custom template and want to add the cart summary to the left bar of certain pages, like for example the contact us page.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction regarding what I should put into the contacts.xml?!

Best,
Ismail

**UPDATE**

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

This is the solution after trying some other stuff. Don't know if this is best practice so please give feedback! :)

Comment: Found it! I will update my question with the answer.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and then accept it. It's the correct solution, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```